# No me reconoce el campo en DJANGO (1054, "Unknown column 'cod_art' in 'field list'")

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Estoy aprendiendo Django y quiero guardar el pedido que haga un usuario pero me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dice que no encuenta la columna cod_art_id pero mi campo solamente se llama cod_art
adjunto los modelos:

```
class Stock(models.Model): #Modelo del stock
cod_art = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
stock = models.IntegerField()
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'stock'

class Pedido(models.Model):   #Modelo para los pedidos
cod_pedido = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
cod_usuario = models.IntegerField()
cod_art = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'pedido'
```

Cuando hago una querie para mostrar todos los productos no me da error. solamente a la hora de hacer un save del pedido.
A la hora de hacer un makemigrations no me toma ningun cambio realizado en los modelos

Codigo cuando quiero hacer el save:

```
variable = Pedido(cod_usuario=1,cod_art=Stock.objects.get(cod_art=1))
variable.save()
```

Comment: Podrias utilizar `Pedido.objects.create(cod_usuario=1, cod_art=1)` saludos

Comment: Me salta el sigueinte error "Cannot assign "1": "Pedido.cod_art" must be a "Stock" instance. " necesita una instancia objeto

Comment: Con `cod_art=Stock.objects.get(cod_art=1)` entonces?

Comment: Sigue el mismo error **(1054, "Unknown column 'cod_art_id' in 'field list'")**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django por defecto espera que la columna en la base de datos tenga el nombre "cod_art_id". Esto se debe a la convención de nombres de Django para las relaciones ForeignKey.

Si deseas mantener el nombre de la columna en la base de datos como 'cod_art', puedes especificar el nombre de la columna utilizando el argumento db_column en el campo ForeignKey

```
cod_cod_art = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='cod_art')
```